# fancybox: Zoom in/out for googlemaps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I use fancybox(http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to show some places on google-maps, one of the examples is folowing..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
    });        
</script>
```

and html

```
Google maps
<ul>
        <li><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Eiffel+Tower,+Avenue+Gustave+Eiffel,+Paris,+France&t=h&z=17">Search results</a></li>
        <li><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://maps.google.com/?ll=48.85796,2.295231&spn=0.003833,0.010568&t=h&z=17">Direct link</a></li>
        <li><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://maps.google.com/?ll=48.859463,2.292626&spn=0.000965,0.002642&t=m&z=19&layer=c&cbll=48.859524,2.292532&panoid=YJ0lq28OOy3VT2IqIuVY0g&cbp=12,151.58,,0,-15.56">Street view</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I canť zoom in/zoom out with mousewheel,
is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you embed Google maps in an `iframe` (the recommended way to embed them into a website) you can't zoom in/out the map using the mouse wheel (you could zoom a street view image though) ... that would be the normal behavior.

Check this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zTgKJ/)** as example with pure html `iframe`.

When you display Google maps in fancybox, they are actually wrapped in an `iframe`, so you can't use the mouse wheel to zoom in or out either .... so regarding your question I don't think it's possible.

It's not a fancybox issue but an html `iframe` limitation.

**EDIT** :

Google map's fusion tables can be zoomed in/out using the mouse wheel ... in this case, those maps should be opened using fancybox `iframe` mode like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "iframe"
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8SM3Q/)**

**My conclusion** : it all depends on the content format. Fancybox doesn't set any limitation to the content inside the `iframe` : whatever you can do in a regular html `iframe`, is what you can do inside fancybox (`iframe` mode).

Comment: @Meloun : interesting, the fusion tables map zooms in/out using the mouse wheel. I guess it all depends on the map format. See my edit answer.